# Strange use of the new keyword

Tags: c#, .net

So I was digging around in the .NET sourcecode, and came across a very strange section. Here is the code:

```
public new Point AutoScrollPosition
{
    get
    {
        return base.AutoScrollPosition;
    }

    set
    {
        base.AutoScrollPosition = value;
    }
}
```

And also:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
new public event EventHandler AutoSizeChanged
{
    add
    {
        base.AutoSizeChanged += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        base.AutoSizeChanged -= value;
    }
}
```

Why is the new keyword used after public? What does it do? What is this called?

Comment: It is used to hide a property called the same name in the base class

Comment: See property overloading. I would expect some attributes along with the declaration. It might change default value, serialization rules, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of the examples you gave are the same. "new" means you have a member of the same name, but you hide it with a new implementation.

```
class A
{
    public string Member { get { return "A"; } }
}

class B : A
{
    public new string Member { get { return "B"; } }
}

A realA = new A();
B realB = new B();
A fakeA = new B();

Console.WriteLine(realA.Member); // Prints "A"
Console.WriteLine(realB.Member); // Prints "B", Only way to print "B" is to be a B and not casted to anything (real B)
Console.WriteLine(fakeA.Member); // Prints "A"
Console.WriteLine((realB as A).Member); // Prints "A", here we won't see hidden members
```

You just have to understand the difference between "new" and "override"

Edit: As @jafar said, omitting new on a derived class is not wrong either. using new only tells the compiler that we want to hide the base class member.

Comment: Just to add that omitting new is no error. It just tells the compiler and us that you know what you are doing when you re-write a method in a derived class.